# How to pass parameters to the function called by ElapsedEventHandler?

Tags: c#, events, timer, elapsed

How to pass parameters to the function called by ElapsedEventHandler?

My code:

```
private static void InitTimer(int Index)
{
    keepAlive[Index] = new Timer();
    keepAlive[Index].Interval = 3000;
    keepAlive[Index].Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(keepAlive_Elapsed[, Index]);
    keepAlive[Index].Start();
}

public static void keepAlive_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e[, int Index])
{

    PacketWriter writer = new PacketWriter();
    writer.AppendString("KEEPALIVE|.\\");
    ServerSocket.Send(writer.getWorkspace(), Index);
    ServerSocket.DisconnectSocket(Index);
}
```

What I want to do is between the brackets ([ and ]).
But just doing it like that obviously doesn't work...

Comment: (It's funny to come back to old questions and see how much you've learned in the past 3 years and how you have evolved. This is one of the reasons I love this site.)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can't do this within the method itself - you have to make your event handler aware of its context, effectively. The simplest way of doing this is with a lambda expression or anonymous method:

```
private static void InitTimer(int Index)
{
    keepAlive[Index] = new Timer();
    keepAlive[Index].Interval = 3000;
    keepAlive[Index].Elapsed += delegate { KeepAliveElapsed(Index); };
    keepAlive[Index].Start();
}

public static void KeepAliveElapsed(int Index)
{    
    PacketWriter writer = new PacketWriter();
    writer.AppendString("KEEPALIVE|.\\");
    ServerSocket.Send(writer.getWorkspace(), Index);
    ServerSocket.DisconnectSocket(Index);
}
```

Here, the anonymous method (the bit with the `delegate` keyword) has created a delegate which knows about the `Index` parameter to `InitTimer`. It just calls the `KeepAliveElapsed` method. I've used the anonymous method syntax because you didn't need the sender or event args; if you *did* need them I'd probably use a lambda expression instead, e.g.

```
private static void InitTimer(int Index)
{
    keepAlive[Index] = new Timer();
    keepAlive[Index].Interval = 3000;
    keepAlive[Index].Elapsed += (sender, args) => KeepAliveElapsed(sender, Index);
    keepAlive[Index].Start();
}

public static void KeepAliveElapsed(object sender, int Index)
{    
    PacketWriter writer = new PacketWriter();
    writer.AppendString("KEEPALIVE|.\\" + sender);
    ServerSocket.Send(writer.getWorkspace(), Index);
    ServerSocket.DisconnectSocket(Index);
}
```

(Note that conventionally the `Index` parameter should be called `index`, btw.)

Comment: I have trouble understanding this. Doesn't the Elapsed event expect a ElapsedEventHandler delegate?

Comment: @lesderid: Parameter names are conventionally in camelCase rather than PascalCase.

Comment: @SWeko: Yes, and we're creating an ElapsedEventHandler, either with an anonymous method or with a lambda expression. That delegate happens to call `KeepAliveElapsed` but that doesn't have to have the same signature at all.

Comment: Missed that. So we are basically doing `timer.Elapsed +=new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, args) => KeepAliveElapsed(index); );`

Comment: @SWeko: Yes, although it would be pretty odd to have the "new EventHandler" part when using a lambda expression.

Comment: @amaranth: If you're sorry, you know it's inappropriate to add a comment try to draw attention to another question. I'm not going to reward that behaviour by answering your question. Please do not do this in future.

Comment: @JonSkeet I understood. Sorry. I have a unclear error